# Lower a polytope into the water $-$ are vertices at the water level connected to those at the bottom?

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

Suppose we take a **convex** polyope $P$ and a face $A$ with vertices $a_1,\ldots, a_n$. We hold the polytope with $A$ flush with the surface and slowly lower it, keeping $A$ parallel to the surface thoughout. We continue lowering until the water level reaches some vertex $b_1$ not belonging to $A$. Then let $b_1,\ldots, b_m$ be all the vertices at the water level. I wonder:

> Is every $b_i$ joined by an edge to some $a_i$?

Seems physically obvious. But so do many facts about polytopes, such as the linear-inequalities/convex-hull definitions being equivalent.

If you consider the part of the polytope between the water level and the plane spanned by $A$ you get a smaller polytope $Q$. This $Q$ has all $a_i,b_j$ as vertices but might have extra vertices created when edges of $A$ pass through the water. Nevertheless all the vertices are contained in one of the two planes. This suggests the following perhaps easier question.

> Suppose $P_1,P_2$ are two parallel planes, and $P$ is a polytope whose every vertex is in either $P_1$ or $P_2$. Is each vertex in $P_1$ joined by an edge to a vertex of $P_2$?

Comment: do you suppose that $P$ is convex? If not then it's not true. Start with a nonconvex pentagon to see it

Comment: @user8268 Yes it's convex. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your second question is **Yes** (and so is the answer to the first).

In general, for every vertex of a (full-dimensional) polytope $P\subset\Bbb R^d$, the directions of the edges incident to that vertex span the whole $\Bbb R^d$.

If a vertex in $P_1$ would have edges only to other vertices in $P_1$, then the span would be of dimension $\le \dim(P_1)= d-1$, hence, not all of $\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: Cool. Does this result have a name or do you know a good reference?

Comment: @Daron I do not know a name. But the statement about the "span of the edge-directions" is seen quickly (and can assumed to be folklore): at each vertex, the edge-directions span a cone, and the polytope is the intersection of all these cones. If one of the cones would not be full-dimensional, then neither would be the poyltope (in contradiction to the assumption). A related result that might interest you is [Balinski's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balinski%27s_theorem). It is about cutting a polytope with a hyperplane, and asking about the connected components of the cut edge-graph.